# Tesseract-OCR training problems

Tags: c, ocr, tesseract, subscript, superscript

I follow the steps in this tutorial http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/TrainingTesseract3 and gives me error on the part 
`mftraining-F-U font_properties unicharset nobatch.tr`

The error I get is:

```
Failed to load font_properties
Reading nobatch.tr ...
nobatch has no defined properties.
!"Missing font_properties entry is a fatal error!":Error:Assert failed:in file mftraining.cpp, line 281
Segmentation fault
```

What you should do is to read superscripts and subscripts.
Any help or advice from any OCR to do this is appreciated.

Comment: please check this [link](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/issues/detail?id=586#c5) I am having same issue and this helps me.

Answer (score 1):

Create file "font_properties"

With data:

font name 1 0 0 1 0

R.T.M again is there about font

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/dawjan/Open_Me/tree/master/Captcha%20Crack/tesseract_training

Answer (score 0):

when i followed that tutorial i had a same problem
'xxx.font_properties' change to 'font_properties' and problem fixed